# How to embed jasper report in jsp page using struts2-jasperreports-plugin

Tags: struts2, jasper-reports

I'm creating a report using jasper report and successfully generated the report with struts2-jasperreports-plugin, in my web application.
the report is displayed in html format, now i need to embed this report in a jsp page, but couldn't find a way to do that.

Could some one please help me?

following is the struts configuration i have used:

```
<action name="myJasperTest" class="com.action.JasperAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success" type="jasper">
                <param name="location">jasper\report4.jasper</param>
                <param name="dataSource">myList</param>
                <param name="format">HTML</param>
                <param name="imageServletUrl">/servlets/image?image=</param>           
            </result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something to manage my layout such as tiles which can help compose pages, and using that simply make a jsp tile with an iframe which targets "myJasperTest".

I don't think there is an easy way to do it with the plugin.  If you're not partial to an iframe solution, you could use Jasper Reports as you would in a Java SE project in your action. Capture the resulting html and using xml tools, or maybe regular expressions to chop up the page the way you want it (removing the header and what not).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, i could use an iframe to solve the problem. Simply gave the iframe name as the target of the form action. 
<s:form action="myJasperTest" target="ac">
 <s:submit value="Generate Report"></s:submit>
</s:form>
<iframe name="ac" width="100%" height="300">